# Fetching Twilio channel with new Conversations API

Tags: twilio, twilio-conversations

I have an application which is using old Chat API and in the documentation for [Chat Channel Migration](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/chat-channel-migration-resource) I saw that channels are automatically migrated to new Conversations API if they have a *private* type. Today I tried creating a private channel and fetching it via Conversation API's endpoint like this:

```
curl -X GET 'https://conversations.twilio.com/v1/Conversations/CHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' -
u $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_TOKEN
```

However, I'm receiving this response:

```
{"code": 20404, "message": "The requested resource /Conversations/CHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX was not found", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404", "status": 404}%
```

I've checked multiple times and confirmed that channel with such SID exists and it has *private* type (fetched along with other channels with old API).

[image: channel mentioned above]

Is there something I'm missing out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Twilio Conversations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/overview) have a [default Conversation service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-resource#using-the-shortened-base-url), but I suspect when you migrate from Chat you will not be using the default service and instead should make API calls to the [service-scoped Conversation resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/service-conversation-resource).

I believe the Chat Service SID is the SID you should use to scope the conversations. So try this request instead:

```
curl -X GET 'https://conversations.twilio.com/v1/Services/ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Conversations/CHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' -
u $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_TOKEN
```